# how to use a class object in other form in vb6

Tags: class, object, vb6

i am trying to access a class object in different form to call its method ..can u plz tell me how can i do it..?
here is my code..

```
Dim a As customers

Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim txt1 As String
Dim txt2 As String
Set a = New customers   
txt1 = Text1.Text
txt2 = Text2.Text
a.userid = txt1
a.log_in txt1, txt2       

End Sub
```

its a code i have written in form 1....for login..
made an object for customer n called loging procedure...
in that if it sucesfully logs in i m opening a new form
homw.show only..
and in home......
option is there
view profile
in which i am showing another form profile
and in its load method want to call a's another method for displaying profile..
how it can know whose profile it should display....here i m getting cofused
as m new to vb help me out...plz..

Answer (score 1):

Implement an init method on the second form and use it in Command1_Click like this

```
    ...
    a.userid = txt1
    a.log_in txt1, txt2   

    Dim oFrm As Form2
    Set oFrm = New Form2
    oFrm.Init a
End Sub
```

In `Init` you can call `Show` to display the instance of `Form2`. You can also move everything you do in `Form_Load` to this simple `Init` method -- like filling comboboxes etc.